# What is the UI element on iPad Photos App?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Please see the youtube:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FC95ARd96wI

notice that the 0:35 , the iPad bottom have a thin photo bar. Is it a private API or I need to create my own or Which UI Element will it be? Thz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's definitely a custom job.  However, it's basically a UIToolbar with a fancy slider on it.  You can easily make the toolbar using Interface Builder, and you could take a simple stab at the slider by taking a regular `UISlider` and giving it some replacement images for its track, thumb, etc.  [See the documentation on `UISlider`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If that doesn't quite work, then you're going to have to get down and dirty in `UIControl` code and make on yourself from scratch (or hope and pray that someone has written an open source version already).